# How to add CSS to a nested JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, css, charts, chart.js, javascript-objects

I have a chart.js bar graph with a nested object `var config`:

```js
var color = Chart.helpers.color;
var config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['8AM','9AM',\*…*\ '11PM','12AM'],

    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.75).rgbString(),
      borderColor: window.chartColors.blue, 
      data: [0, 0, 0, \* … *\ 0] 
}] }  
  options: {title: {text: 'Chart.js Combo Time Scale'},
    scales: {xAxes: [{ticks: {source: 'data'}, stacked: true, display: true}], 
             yAxes: [{ticks: {min:0, max:60}, stacked: true}] }}}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

The chart.js API comes with own custom styling options, such as `backgroundColor`, but does not suffice; I seek to add the following CSS to `datasets`, the property responsible for chart bars:

```css
.glowing-border {border: 2px solid #dadada; border-radius: 7px;}

.glowing-border:focus { 
outline: none;
border-color: #9ecaed;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;}
```

The goal is  decorate chart bars with a glowing border. I've tried defining a blank image with CSS added, then invoking the storing variable in borderColor as follows:

```js
var img = new Image();
img.classList.add = 'glowing-border';
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var fillPattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
// ...
label: 'Dataset 1',
      borderColor: fillPattern;
```

to no avail. Inserting a variable into `borderColor` seems to work when `img` src is defined, yet doing so does not meet the goals here. Inline styling doesn't seem to work either (unless predefined in chart.js).

How can I add CSS to nested object properties? Else, any alternatives to glowing borders with chart.js?

Comment: Have you tried using the !important flag?

Comment: In what way? @SmokeyDawson